# What regex will emulate the default behavior of split() in python?

Tags: python, regex

Using split() I can easily create from a string the list of tokens that are divided by space:

```
>>> 'this is a test 200/2002'.split()
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', '200/2002']
```

How do I do the same using re.compile and re.findall? I need something similiar to the following example but without splitting the "200/2002".

```
>>> test = re.compile('\w+')
>>> test.findall('this is a test 200/2002')
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', '200', '2002']
```

Comment: `str.split` doesn't actually use a regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should output the desired list:

```
>>> test = re.compile('\S+')
>>> test.findall('this is a test 200/2002')
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', '200/2002']
```

[`\S`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is anything but a whitespace (space, tab, newline, ...).

From `str.split()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) :

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently,
>   splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace
>   with a None separator returns [].

`findall()` with the above regex should have the same behaviour :

```
>>> test.findall(" a\nb\tc   d ")
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> " a\nb\tc   d ".split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```